# RichTextBox C# Set caret location winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am building a chat application where the user enters its text to a richtextbox.

In the rich text box there is an initial text which says: "Me: ".

Now, when the user press the Home button I want the caret to be located after the "Me: " string. So for Shift+Home combination or for triple mouse click or for Ctrl + left cursor etc..

Any way it can be done?

I've already tried

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetCaretPos(int X, int Y);
```

thanks in advance,
Oz.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the caret position with the [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) and [`SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength.aspx) properties of the rich text box. Set `SelectionLength` to 0 and then set `SelectionStart` to the location where you want the caret to appear.

The documentation for `SelectionStart` says:

> If no text is selected in the control, this property indicates the insertion point, or caret, for new text.

---

The Win32 API function `SetCaretPos` is much too low level for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Winforms: [RichTextBox.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) & set RichTextBox.SelectionLength to 0.

WPF: [RichTextBox.CaretPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to the grace period, it now looks like I copied your answer!  ;-)

Comment: Indeed haha, after I was done editing I saw you already posted.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx) method:

```
public void Select(
    int start,
    int length
)

richTextBoxUserText.Select(richTextBoxUserText.TextLength, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = Pos;
RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score -2):

Found it googling on the property SelectionProtected

```
richTextBoxUserText.Text = INITIAL_TEXT;
richTextBoxUserText.SelectAll();
richTextBoxUserText.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBoxUserText.SelectionProtected = true;
richTextBoxUserText.SelectionLength = 0;
richTextBoxUserText.SelectionStart = richTextBoxUserText.TextLength + 1;
```

Comment: @David, the solution for protecting the text from being deleted is using the SelectionProtected property. for preventing the user selecting it, additional work is needed.... where did you tell me this?

Comment: @os You don't mention protecting text anywhere in your original question. Also, I'm pretty sure 'richTextBoxUserText.SelectionStart = richTextBoxUserText.TextLength + 1' will throw an outofrange exception.

Comment: @David yep i didn't mention because i wasn't aware of it... And it doesn't throw

Comment: @oz I'm sorry I didn't mention protecting but I didn't see that part of your question.

Comment: @oz Fair enough, but I'm surprised at that... you're setting the selection to the end of the text + 1.

Comment: "If you set this property to a location beyond the length of the text in the control, the selection start position will be placed after the last character." - that explains it... your sloppy coding is compensated for!  :)