# c# Richtextbox move caret to x,y location

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, move, caret

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RichTextBox C# Set caret location winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441455/richtextbox-c-set-caret-location-winforms)

I am working on a project where I am reading from a terminal(tn3270) interface which has a caret postion listed as X,Y which I want to pass on to my richtextbox that is displaying the full terminal interface. I have tried looking on google multiple ways, but all I can seem to find is how to GET the x,y location of the caret in the richtextbox.

I am looking to have a function that can be

```
private void SetCaretLocation(iX,iY);
```

:EDIT:

```
    private void SetCaretPos(int iX,int iY)
    {
        int iLen = 0;
        int iRow = 0;
        foreach (string str in richTextBox1.lines)
        {
            iRow++;
            iLen += str.Length;
            if (iRow == iX)
                break;
        }
        iLen += iY;

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = iLen;
    }
```

I seem to be getting some what close. But the position does not seem to match up correctly.

Comment: What is the row separator? NewLine?

Comment: \n should be the new line seperator.

Comment: In regards to joshhendo's commend, this is not quite the same issue. That answer was for positioning at the start. I am looking to position somewhere in the middle of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is how it should be done but its 1 way:

```
private void SetCaretPosition(int rows, int col)
{
    int curPos = 0;
    if (richTextBox1.Lines.Length >= rows)
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; ++i)
        {
           curPos += richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length + 1; //add 1 for the newline character
        }
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = curPos + col; 
    }
    else
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();             
}
```

Edit:

I didn't realize you had also posted an edit. You need to consider the new line character. 1 if its \n, 2 if its \r\n

Answer (score 0):

check the SelectionStart method
You can use the SelectionStart property of your RichTextBox control to "Gets or sets the starting point of text selected in the text box."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

The code example is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx

Comment: Somewhat on the correct track for what I was thinking (best answer so far). I have an idea of what might work. I'm going to play with this and a few other things and see what I can come up with.